# New line matcher "no match"

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I'm writing a java server and always read requests form the browser. For example, I have in browser `http://localhost:8080/great` and read this request like

```
GET /great HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36 OPR/29.0.1795.47
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

As the next step in my program I need to get text between GET and  HTTP/1.1 . So, in this case `/great` I try to use matcher. But it says that there is no match. Can anyone explain why?

Here is a code:

```
  public void run() {
        try {
while(true) {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serSock.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();
    request = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;
    while (!(inputLine = in.readLine()).equals("")) {
        request.append(inputLine + "\r\n");
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)GET(.*)HTTP/1.1:*[\\n\\r].*", Pattern.MULTILINE);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(request);
   System.out.println(request);


    String rev= matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(rev);
}
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in Pattern.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't mean to put `:*` in your pattern.  Your example request, like any valid HTTP request, doesn't have any colons after `HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: I personally would probably just call `readLine()` on this and then use `.split(" ")` to get the verb and URI.  Pattern matching is overkill for something this trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern should probably be `Pattern.compile("^GET (.*) HTTP/1\\.1$.*", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL)`

Some of the errors in your pattern:

- As mentioned in the comment by @VGR, `:*` shouldn't be there, but since `*` is used, it means zero or more occurrences. And zero occurrences it is in your case.
- `[\\n\\r]` which, after string escaping has taken place, would be `[\n\r]`, which means *one* of the characters `newline` *or* `carriage-return`. Not both. You should just have used `\r\n`, without `[]` and in reversed order. But `$` is better to use.

**The main problem why you don't get the regular expression to work** is however that you never call any of the matching methods on the `Matcher` object. You need to add `matcher.matches()` (or `find()` or `lookingAt()`) before you call `matcher.group(1)`. *(I should have noticed this earlier.)*